# Python program sometimes exit with "IndexError: string index out of range" and sometimes runs fine

Tags: python, index-error

I'm learning Python and decided to upgrade a version of the hangman game that was used as an example in one of the courses I watched, the code turned out like this:

```
import random
word_dictionary = {
    1:  "mouse",
    2:  "house",
    3:  "show",
    4:  "see",
    5:  "leave",
    6:  "shower",
    7:  "showcase",
    8: "coding",
    9:  "elephant",
    10:  "apartment",
}

random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
random_word = word_dictionary[random_number]

secret_word = random_word
word_len = len(secret_word)
guess = None
tip = 0
tip_num = None
tip_previous = None
tip_position = None
tip_model_formula = "_"*word_len
tip_model_list = list(tip_model_formula)
send_tip = None

print("Word has", word_len, " letters")
while guess != secret_word:
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    if guess != secret_word:
        print("Wrong answer! Try again!")
        tip += 1
        if tip == 5:
            tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            tip_position = secret_word[tip_num]
            tip_model_list[tip_num] = tip_position
            send_tip = "".join(tip_model_list)
            tip_previous = tip_num
            print("here's a tip:\n" + send_tip)
        if tip == 10:
            tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            while tip_num == tip_previous:
                tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            tip_position = secret_word[tip_num]
            tip_model_list[tip_num] = tip_position
            send_tip = "".join(tip_model_list)
            tip_previous = tip_num
            print("here's a tip:\n" + send_tip)
        if tip == 15:
            tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            while tip_num == tip_previous:
                tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            tip_position = secret_word[tip_num]
            tip_model_list[tip_num] = tip_position
            send_tip = "".join(tip_model_list)
            tip_previous = tip_num
            print("here's a tip:\n" + send_tip)
        if tip == 16:
            print("You lost!")
            exit()

print("You win!")
```

(What this does is pick a random word from the dictionary to be the secret word and have the player take guesses on it, every 5 attempts, the player gets 1 tip, which is one letter of the word, after 16 attempts, you lose and have to restart).

When I run it, sometimes it runs as expected, but sometimes it exits with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "E:\Program Files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/rafae/PycharmProjects/Beginning/Beg.py", line 55, in <module>
    tip_position = secret_word[tip_num]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I have no idea why this randomly happens and have been trying to figure out for an hour without success.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: TL;DR `random.randint(1, 10)` sometimes picks 10

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  You posted over 50 lines of code for a 5-line problem.  Insert appropriate `print` statements to trace your program values and execution.  *Then* you have a good Stack Overflow question ... although you've likely figured out the problem yourself, by then.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
            tip_num = random.randint(0, word_len)
            tip_position = secret_word[tip_num]
```

`randint` returns a number between its first and second arguments **inclusive of both**.  That means that it can return a result of `word_len`, which is one past the end of `secret_word`.

Comment: so `tip_position = random.choice(secret_word)` is advised instead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But then how do you get `tip_num`? It's used for other things as well...

Comment: The easiest fix is to just use `random.randint(0, word_len-1)` and then nothing else has to change.  I think the way to use `choice` would be something like `random.choice(i for i, letter in enumerate(tip_model_list) if letter == '_')`.

Comment: @Samwise That's apparently not the issue, cause even after adding a security check to not allow the number to be higher than ```secret_word```, the issue persists.

Comment: You have the same bug in multiple spots.  Make sure you're fixing it in all of them (or better yet, turn this into a function so you don't have to repeat the same logic in multiple places)!

Comment: @Samwise I had fixed it in all the spots... problem persisted, but after turning it to a function, the problem is gone, idk why, but if it works I will take it lol. I would have made it a function from the beginning, but I only remembered those existed halfway through, well, living and learning, not gonna forget next time. Thanks for the help!